# Angular 4 Chrome HTML input number always rounding to hundredths

Tags: html, angular, binding, floating-point, rounding

I need to be able to save the number I input to the thousandths , but the chrome input type number always rounds it to hundredths. I have tried setting step="any" . Not sure what direction to go to make this work.

```
<div >
    <input type="number" 
    [(ngModel)]="mObject.AMOUNT" 
    formControlName="amount"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step any did work it was the edmx causing the issue. It would read the values just fine fromt he database but it would round them during save to the database. After rebuilding the edmx this worked fine. This was an api/.net issue.